# Tensorflow Data API: repeat()

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

The following code is a snippet from "Hands on machine learning with scimitar-learn, Keras and tensorflow".
I understand everything in the following code, except the chaining the `.repeat(repeat)` function in second line.

I know that repeat is repeating the dataset elements (i.e., in this case the file paths) and if the argument is set to `None` or left empty the repetition will continues forever until the function which using it decides when to stop.

As you can see in the code bellow, the author is setting the `repeat()` argument to `None`;

1 - basically I want to know why the author decided to do such?

2 - or is it because the code is trying to simulate a situation which the dataset is not fitting in the memory, if this is the case then in real situation we should avoid `repeat()`, am I correct?

```py
def csv_reader_dataset(filepaths, repeat=1, n_readers=5,
                       n_read_threads=None, shuffle_buffer_size=10000,
                       n_parse_threads=5, batch_size=32):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filepaths, seed = 42).repeat(repeat)
    dataset = dataset.interleave(
        lambda filepath: tf.data.TextLineDataset(filepath).skip(1),
        cycle_length = n_readers, num_parallel_calls = n_read_threads)
    
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls = n_parse_threads)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset.prefetch(1)

train_set = csv_reader_dataset(train_filepaths, repeat = None)
valid_set = csv_reader_dataset(valid_filepaths)
test_set = csv_reader_dataset(test_filepaths)


keras.backend.clear_session()
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape = X_train.shape[-1: ]),
    keras.layers.Dense(30, activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

m_loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error
m_optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = 1e-3)

batch_size = 32
model.compile(loss = m_loss, optimizer = m_optimizer, metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_set, steps_per_epoch = len(X_train) // batch_size, epochs = 10, validation_data = valid_set)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another copy of the same question on book's author git repo.
The issue is clarified; it was due to a bug in Keras 2.0.

Read more on: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/issues/407

Answer (score 1):

For your questions, I think:

- tf.data API won't easily lead to out-of-memory easily as it loads data given the file paths or tfrecrods (compressed mode). Hence, *repeat()* does not thing with memory here; instead, it is used for data-transforming.
- I have to use repeat(#) when setting steps_per_epoch to #. Say your **batch_num = 32**, and **steps_per_epoch = 100//32 = 3 -> require 3 * 32 = 96 samples per epoch** but your data has 80 samples only. Then, I have to use data.repeat(2) to have totally 160 samples that 80 samples in repeat_1 and the first 16 samples in repeat_2 would be used within 1 epoch. This is to prevent the error *Input run out of data*.